# How to handle script dependencies in angular 2 module published to npm

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have published an angular 2 library to npm recently.I have listed all the dependency scripts in the libraries package.json file. when I run `npm install my-library` all the dependency scripts are not installed.So, my question is how to install the dependency scripts while installing the library.

Comment: are you using angular cli

Comment: yes I am using angular-cli

Comment: try the answer i gave you bellow

Comment: please check the edited the question.

Comment: well that's another question :/

Comment: yeah. My bad. please check that also